# Filtering list on multiple conditions based on multiple properties in Java

Tags: java, guava

I'm using [Google guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) 17.0. I have a class `Employee` containing only two properties namely, `id` of type `Integer` and `salary` of type `BigDecimal`.

I'm trying to filter based on these two properties as follows.

```
List<Employee>entireList=null; //This list is already populated somehow by a list of employee objects.

entireList = FluentIterable.from(entireList).filter(new Predicate<Employee>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(Employee employee) {
        if(filters.containsKey("id")&&filters.get("id") instanceof Integer&&filters.containsKey("salary")&&filters.get("salary") instanceof BigDecimal)
        {
            return ((Integer)filters.get("id")).equals(employee.getId())&&((BigDecimal)filters.get("salary")).compareTo(employee.getSalary())>=0;
        }

        if(filters.containsKey("id")&&filters.get("id") instanceof Integer)
        {
            return ((Integer)filters.get("id")).equals(employee.getId());
        }

        if(filters.containsKey("salary")&&filters.get("salary") instanceof BigDecimal)
        {
            return ((BigDecimal)filters.get("salary")).compareTo(employee.getSalary())>=0;
        }
        return false;
    }
}).toList();
```

`filters` is a `Map<String, Object>`. When this map contains both keys `id` and `salary`, the first condition in the `apply()` method is evaluated to true and accordingly, it should filter based on both the properties. It however, filters the list based on only on one of them.

So how to apply filtering on multiple properties here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty perfectly obfuscated. So that it even may work without anyone noticing.

Let's go through:

```
 filters.containsKey("id")
```

Useless, drop it.

```
filters.get("id") instanceof Integer
```

Better throw if someone has put something else in. So drop it, too.

```
return ((Integer)filters.get("id")).equals(employee.getId())&&((BigDecimal)filters.get("salary")).compareTo(employee.getSalary())>=0;
```

What would you do with 5 or 10 conditions? Combinatorial explosion?

So what about this?

```
Integer id = (Integer) filters.get("id");
if (id != null && !id.equals(employee.getId())) return false;

BigDecimal salary = (BigDecimal) filters.get("salary");
if (salary != null && ((salary.compareTo(employee.getSalary()) < 0)) return false;

return true;
```

Comment: The filtering condition is still not applied on both properties, when both the filters are set. It should be like in conjunction with an SQL  statement - `SELECT * FROM employee WHERE id=10 and salary>=10000`. It is just like one of them at a time like `...WHERE id=10` or `...WHERE salary>=10000`. There is no `and` criteria applied.

Comment: @Tiny Then that bug must be in code that you haven't shown.

Comment: There is no extra code complexity. There are approximately 90 rows in the list, `entireList`. It filters only based on `id` even though both the filter properties are set and have appropriate values. The `salary` filter has no effect :) (Though let me try in a stand-alone application. It is currently in JSF) @Boann

Comment: @Tiny Then write a test. Put a single item into the `entireList` and run it through. The five lines I wrote leave no place for *such* a bug. Some condition may be always wrong, but it definitely computes a conjunction, that's sure.

Comment: I don't know the reason why it doesn't work in JSF. It worked just fine in a stand-alone application. I have just tried. I have also replaced this anonymous class with a nested class in the JSF managed bean but still no luck. It should be a separate question. Thanks.

Comment: @Tiny No idea about JSF, but be assured that such an error can't be in the few lines. Probable causes are 1. filtering a wrong list, 2. passing wrong arguments, 3. the list or the map changing in between, etc. Adding some `assert`s could help, and obviously tests.